# How to see a list of all pages in Visio 2016?

Tags: microsoft-visio, tabs

I've found out how to do it for Visio 2010, as I would like to print the list of all pages in a separate tab, but I can't find the small forward backward buttons to the left of the page tabs(status bar) in Visio 2016.
 "Right click on the small forward backward buttons to the left of the page tabs(status bar) pops a list of the pages in the document :)"
Is there a way to have the same for Visio 2016 as well?
Thank you

Comment: The page tabs interface in Visio 2010 is far clearer and easier to use. The tab size increased with the page text length, and it was easy to see which text applies to which tab, In Visio 2016 you can name a page to be "Page-1      Page-2" and it just looks like you have 2 pages! Wrong!

Answer (score 0):

To the right of the page tabs there is an entry "All". Click that. Or press Alt-F3.